# Get a list of all tags in of all child objects in an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get all tags into a `list<string>` but it seems that I can only loop through a tags when its a char my best try was using `toString()`but that also doesn't work.

```
public List<string> GetWorldObjectsTag()
{
    var worldObjects = new List<string>();

    foreach (string child in worldOBjectsPrefab.gameObject.tag.ToString())
    {
        worldObjects.Add(child);
    }

    return worldObjects;
}
```

```
foreach(string name in currentWorldGen.GetWorldObjectsTag())
{
    Debug.Log(name);
    if (name == sawBlade.tag)
    {
        Instantiate(sawBlade, new Vector2(trans.position.x + Camera.main.transform.position.x + 20, trans.position.y), Quaternion.identity);

    }
    else
    {
        Instantiate(testBlock, new Vector2( trans.position.x + Camera.main.transform.position.x + 20, trans.position.y), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

This might not be a great way of doing it so if anyone has a better idea please tell me.

**Edit:**

These are the objects I used

[image: picture of materials]

**Answer**
I'm able to loop through the transforms and I can revert those transforms back to a gameObject simply by doing `transform.gameObject`
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please could you provide more context here? We don't know the type of `worldOBjectsPrefab.gameObject.tag` for example.

Comment: Showing a screenshot really doesn't give us the type information - certainly not in an easy-to-comprehend way.

Comment: you need to itterate the objects, and get the tag.tostring for each inside the loop..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can loop through all the child gamebjects using a foreach:

If the above doesn't work then try with Transform:

```
foreach (Transform child in worldObjectPrefab.transform)
{
    // Here you can access child.tag and add do what you need to do.
}
```

Sorry but I don't have access to Unity right now.
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: using GameObject doesn't work, I did use the Transform already for the position but I'll see if I can also use it for other things (I'm fairly new to game development)

Answer (score 0):

In the Unity source code you can see that [`Transform`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Transform/ScriptBindings/Transform.bindings.cs) implements the interface [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable) so you can basically do

```
public List<string> GetWorldObjectsTag()
{
    var listOfTags = new List<string>();

    foreach(Transform child in worldOBjectsPrefab.transform)
    {
        listOfTags.Add(child.name);
    }

    return listOfTags;
}
```

pretty similar under the hood would be using [Linq `Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) like

```
public List<string> GetWorldObjectsTag()
{
    return ((IEnumerable<Transform>) worldOBjectsPrefab.transform).Select(child => child.tag).ToList();
}
```

since it is a type-less `IEnumerable` in both cases you have to explicitly tell it to use the type `Transform`.